# Define checkbox true-value and false-value to a non-string value (other primitives, object, or expression)

Tags: vue.js

I can't set my v-model value to anything other than a string when the corresponding checkbox is checked/unchecked.

https://jsbin.com/haqofus/edit?html,console,output

```
<div id="app">
    <div><input type="checkbox" v-model="checkbox" true-value="null" false-value="new Date()" @change="log(checkbox)">checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" v-model="checkbox2" true-value=null false-value='{ "prop": "value" }' @change="log(checkbox2)">checkbox2</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" v-model="checkbox3" true-value="methodReturningNewDate" false-value="methodReturningObject" @change="log(checkbox3)">checkbox3</div>
</div>

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { 
    checkbox: "init",
    checkbox2: "init2",
    checkbox3: "init3"
  },
  methods: {
    log: function (message) {
      console.log(message);
    },
    methodReturningNewDate: function () {
      return new Date();
    },
    methodReturningObject: function () {
      return { "prop": "value" };
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the values or else they are evaluated as strings,  i.e. `:false-value="new Date()"`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { 
    checkbox: "init",
    checkbox2: "init2",
    foo: {
      a: 1,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    log: function (message) {
      console.log(message);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkbox" true-value="null" :false-value="new Date()" @change="log(checkbox)">checkbox
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkbox2" true-value=null :false-value="foo" @change="log(checkbox2)">checkbox2
</div>
```